# The difference in runtime when using master node connection and multicast mode of GridDB

Tags: griddb

I am trying to measure GridDB performance using [sample1.py](https://github.com/griddb/python_client/blob/master/sample/sample1.py) with GridDB python client.

- When using [multicast mode](https://docs.griddb.net/architecture/structure-of-griddb/#cluster-configuration-methods), it took 3.714s. I used this command: "time python sample/sample1.py 239.0.0.1 31999 griddb admin admin"
- I tried using the master node instead of the multicast address and the time was reduced to 0.323s.

  The command was : "time python sample/sample1.py MASTER_NODE_IP_ADDRESS 10001 griddb admin admin".

=> Event results are the same, but there are more than 10 times different in the execution time.

**Why does the performance differ so much and when should we use the multicast mode?**

Answer (score 0):

If you just connect to the master node, you will only be able see containers stored on the master node.

It is important to note, the initial connection time only occurs once so it's not fair to characterize it as being 10x slower. In your system it takes 3.5 seconds and and the actual operations take .3 seconds. Repeating those same operations would take another .3 seconds. In a real world application, the initialization time doesn't count towards actual system performance.

If you have an application that only performs a few operations, I find FIXED_LIST mode to connect faster.